# Curly brackets appear when reading file

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I've got a question concerning python and tkinter. I'd like to generate a message widget out of file content. The problem is that curly brackets appear around each line, for example:

```
{line1
}{line2
}{line3}
```

This is my code:

```
def read_data(self):
  master = Tk()
  a = open("DATEIPFAD.txt")
  msg = Message(master, text = [line for line in a])
  msg.config(bg="#A9F5A9", font=("Helvetica", 12))
  msg.pack()
  augenverletzung.close()
```

I tried it with read, readline and readlines as well, but these methods neither lead to the desired result. 
Does anyone have an idea what to do to get rid of the curly brackets?

Thank you very much beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text=` parameter of Message() expects a string; you're passing a list.  The curly braces are an artifact of the automatic type conversion between the Python and Tcl environments - if a list was actually expected, then those braces would be needed for the Tcl side to interpret the data as a list.

Try `text = a.read()` to pass an actual string.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! This works now. I think, I've made a mistake the first time, I've tried the read() method.